# @Subscribe and @Produce keywords in java on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I came upon a project that uses this event manager:
[otto](https://github.com/square/otto)

Some classes that use this manager have @Produce and @Subscribe near some of their methods.

I couldn't get any useful information on google, so what I'm asking is, how these keywords work? Are they custom made by library, or are constant in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just some custom **Java annotations** from their library:

https://github.com/square/otto/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto: Produce.java and Subscribe.java